# Pronunciation of -eons for -ger verbs with nous

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, conjugaison

For -ger verbs (e.g. nager, changer, corriger) the e is kept in the nous form to keep the g soft, but is the -eons ending pronounced exactly the same as the -ons ending ? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: The *e* is silent so yes, the -eons are pronounced the same as the -ons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phonetically there is no difference between nous partageons et nous parlons regarding the -eons and -ons endings. It's like you said. Keep the g soft.

Note that this e is not introduced in all the tenses and persons.

See, e.g. the conjugation of partager.

Nous partageons mais nous partagions (imperfect tense).

Past simple:

je partageai tu partageas il partagea nous partageâmes vous partageâtes

etc.

https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/premier-groupe/partager/